# Is Cloud Firestore a good alternative to CDN?

Tags: database, firebase, caching, cdn, google-cloud-firestore

In the docs, they claims that Cloud Firestore duplicates data in multiple servers located in different regions across the world.

My question is : By using Cloud Firestore, do i need to cache my data even though ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Firestore synchronously replicates data for durability and availability, rather than for serving speed. In this sense, it is very different from a CDN or a latency cache.

The Mobile and Web SDKs do store data locally though and provide a concept called latency compensation, so on that side it's got you covered out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

Firestore is a document-based storage system. It's typically used as a database for your app, so for content that changes more regularly.

A CDN is a caching layer for delivering (mostly) static assets to regionally diverse users. I'd recommend looking at [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) for that.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe i've used a wrong term. I meant Caching rather than CDN. Because even if it's true that CDN usually store static content, it can be possible to cache dynamic data. I wanted to know how firestore can help for this. Or should i use the http cache system ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache they have mentioned about the request level cache , not sure about 'configure caching behavior for dynamic content data'